# React Typescript - Adding custom attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, custom-attributes

React Typescript allow to add custom data-* attributes.
But is it possible to add custom attributes like 'name' || 'test' act. ?

```
<span name="I'm causing a type error" data-test="I'm Working"/>
```

Bold added by me.

> type error: Type '{ children: Element; name: string; data-test:
>   string; }' is not assignable to type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLSpanElement>'.
>   **Property 'name' does not exist on type**
>   'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLSpanElement>'.
>   TS232

```
"react": "^16.7.0",
"typescript": "^3.2.4",
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

in react 16+ it is possible, [see](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html)

probem is that typescript didnt know about it(yet)

but you can still add @ts ignore for typechecking

```
{ //@ts-ignore
  <span name="I'm causing a type error" data-test="I'm Working"/>
}
```

Comment: Yes, that what I thought.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm using React 17 with TypeScript, but my project still fails to compile because the property doesn't exist on the element (e.g. anchor tag). That blog post makes it sound like it should just work, am I missing something?

Answer (score 37):

there is another way...
skipping the static check (typescript don't do dynamic)

```
{ 
  const allowedProps = {test: "not-data-attribute"}
  <span {...allowedProps}/>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

simple add custom attribute start with `data-`, in some case you may start with `aria-`

```
<div data-attr={3} data-nothing="super">hover</div>
```

it seems typescript knows custom attribute with those prefix, check this [link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html)

Answer (score 2):

Create any file with extension `.d.ts` in your project
and just extend the button interface in the JSX namespace.
I'm using this for creating amp pages with React.

```
declare namespace JSX {
    interface ExtendedButton
        extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
            React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
            HTMLButtonElement
        > {
        customAttribute?: string;
    }

    interface IntrinsicElements {
        button: ExtendedButton;
    }
}
```