# How do I write the content attribute in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microdata

this my code

```
<div  itemProp={"offers"} itemScope  itemType={"http://schema.org/Offer"}>
        <span  itemProp="price" content="10.00">{10}</span>
 </div>
```

I get this error.

> Type '{ children: string; itemProp: string; content: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLSpanElement>'.
>     Property 'content' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLSpanElement>'.

I think the problem is content.

Comment: you shouldn't pass custom props to native HTML elements (like you did with `span` and `div`), instead, wrap them with a React component

Comment: You can set an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[React Typescript - Adding custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869777/react-typescript-adding-custom-attribute)

```
 <div itemProp={"offers"} itemScope itemType={"http://schema.org/Offer"}>
          <span itemProp="price" {...{content: '10.00'}}>
            {10}
          </span>
  </div>
```